# Wrap framer motion into a custom component in Next 13 (App Router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I tried to use Framer Motion on my Next.js with App router, and I've tried to use the `"use client"` at the top of the page. It works. But what if I want the motion framer to run on the component/page server? A thought popped into my mind: what if I create a custom component with a `"use client"` at the beginning of the line of code? This way, it could also be used on other server components as a reusable component (I hope).

```
"use client"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

export default function Motion () {
  return motion
}
```

It's bad. But I don't know how to deal with. And then I tried to use this component like this

```
<Motion.div />
```

but it show an error like this
[image: Error sample]

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this reusable. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

***[DEPRECATED]!***

Hi everyone who had the same problem!

I just found a solution! Apparently, it's enough to export the default motion instead of wrapping it back into a custom component. like this

```
"use client"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

export default motion
```

This won't work when we start use like this on some page with server component

```
<Motion.div>Test</Motion.div>
```

and will get this error

```
Cannot access .div on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.
```